# The same version Google Play Services, responds different and inconsistently on different phones

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services, nexus-4

Given that multiple phones having the latest and same version, different builds (oem related??) of Google Play Services running the the same signed app from the *alpha* Google Play Store  is responding differently on a particular phone. 3 out of 4 phones run without issue using works on 3 phones that are either KitKat or Lollipop for the following code that checks if GPS is available.

```
 int result = 0;
    try {
        result = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The 4 phone gets the already well documented error 'The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 6587000 but found 7095000.'

**How can this be?**

All of the phones have the same version of GPServices app installed with only build # variants.

My client has borrowed a Nexus 4 phone running 4.4.4 with only 524mb free space and 928mb free ram.  This is the phone having the issue and returning the  ... Expected 6587000 but found 7095000 ... error. Seems that the apk (manifest gps version # and dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services should be resolved already as part of the apk and the error almost seems like a incorrect message.

Since the Google Play Services is a proprietary Google api, what are the next best steps to resolve or debug this?

Free space/memory related, OEM related, OS Version related, other?

Comment: `Expected 6587000 but found 7095000` is not at all dependent on what is on the device - it is solely around the version of the Google Play Service SDK (which expected 6587000) and what is in your manifest (which is 7095000) so something is wrong with your build/import process. Can you post your build.gradle and Manifest?

Comment: I'll post that later, but here my issue, the same exact apk gets that message on 1 phone, but not in 3 others. If the build was bad, it should happen on all 4 phones.  This is NOT the case, my belief is that on the 1 phone it's getting some kind of error, but I'm getting the incorrect error message.